# Location of question review link?

Tags: support

Sorry, this is kind of a stupid question. Where is the location of the link to access https://www.stackoverflow.com/review? is there one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review - This is working for me, what are you expecting differently?

Comment: I’m referring to a physical link I can reach from the home page.

Comment: @Laif you can always press the [reviews button in the top right](https://i.imgur.com/dYgCSXb.png)

Comment: @VLAZ That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid answer for a stupid question: there is an icon in the top right to link to reviews
[image]
Thanks @VLAZ

Comment: It's not a stupid question. The icon doesn't appear to have anything to do with the content it hides, so it's perfectly natural to be confused. :)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas And it doesn't provide an alt text ... oh wait, it does.

Comment: @Tom Ah yes.. just let me hover every single thing on the page, or better yet, search the DOM, because that's what good web design requires.

Comment: Yeah the alt text would only be useful if the image was broken, or if using a screen reader. Otherwise it's just a grey little icon at the top of the screen that appears irrelevant.